# why $\nu = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ is $\sigma $ additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu_i)$ with $(i= 1,2)$ are two difference measure space.

Now if at least one of them is finite we need to prove $\nu = \mu_1-\mu_2$ is sigma-additive.

We can show this by countable partition that $\mu_1(\bigcup E_i) - \mu_2(\bigcup E_i) = \sum\mu_1(E_i) - \sum\mu_2(E_2)$

then comes the problem why we can rearange the infinite sequence to $\sum(\mu_1-\mu_2)(E_i)$?  Since the sequence does not absolutely convergence?

Comment: for case two $\mu_1(\bigcup E_i) - \mu_2(\bigcup E_i) = \sum\mu_1(E_i) - \sum\mu_2(E_2)$ is absolutely convergence hence we can rearange freely,for the first case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you have two non-negative sequences of numbers $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}$, and we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\infty$, and $b:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ is finite, then we can subtract their sums as usual, and you don't have to appeal to any rearrangement theorems. This is because the partial sums satisfy
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-b_i)\geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right) - b
\end{align}
So, if we take the limit on both sides as $n\to \infty$, we see that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(a_i-b_i)=\infty$ as well. (The case for finite limits follows simply because of limit rules for sequences).